# References to main form from tframe

Tags: forms, unit-testing, delphi

I using Delphi Turbo.

I have main unit 
**main_u and form main:tmain** 
then I have next unit 
**dok_f_u and Tdok_f = class(TFrame)**

On main form there is `pagecontrol1:tpagecontrol` and code with open new document as another tabsheet on page control dynamically and create `Tdok_f` frame for every tabsheet.

`tmain` have some method to do this :

```
procedure Tmain.opendoctab(i: integer); // i: numbe of doc
```

this procedure create new tabsheet and put new created `tdok_f` on it and make it active one.

Documents are referring to any other documents and on Tdok_f there is list of relative docs - after dblclick on list, selected relative document should be open. So I add main_u in USES in t_dok_f unit and use in code method from tmain
main.opendoctab(xyz);

it was working with no problem but after develop application a lot I found that it is not working.

What I found that main object in unit `dok_f_u` is not the same that is in main_u.
Like there are many main forms.
When i call `main.showmodal;` from `dok_f_u` i have visible 2 separated forms on the screen. like two tmain object(form) are created .

Please help

Comment: Your design appears too promiscuous. Keep these form references private and provide an interface to perform the actions.

Comment: Thanks for response. I found problem meantime - in program unit there was `Application.CreateForm(Tmain, main);` 2 times.

Comment: That's a consequence of the poor design and the misuse of global form ref vars.